# Tauri does not get .env.production when running tauri build

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, tauri

I've got a react app and implemented tauri to it so I can make it a desktop application.

I have two .env files: .env.development and .env.production.
When i run `tauri dev` everything works correctly, but when I run `tauri build` is running without the enviroment variables in the production or the development env files.

I'm attaching a snap of my tauri.conf.json as I hope it helps.

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@tauri-apps/cli/schema.json",
  "build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm start",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:3000",
    "distDir": "../build"
  },
  "package": {
    "productName": "AppName",
    "version": "1.2.3"
  },
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": true
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "category": "DeveloperTool",
      "copyright": "",
      "deb": {
        "depends": []
      },
      "externalBin": [],
      "icon": [
        "icons/32x32.png",
        "icons/128x128.png",
        "icons/128x128@2x.png",
        "icons/icon.icns",
        "icons/icon.ico"
      ],
      "identifier": "com.myappname.app",
      "longDescription": "",
      "macOS": {
        "entitlements": null,
        "exceptionDomain": "",
        "frameworks": [],
        "providerShortName": null,
        "signingIdentity": null
      },
      "resources": [],
      "shortDescription": "",
      "targets": "all",
      "windows": {
        "certificateThumbprint": null,
        "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
        "timestampUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "security": {
      "csp": null
    },
    "updater": {
      "active": false
    },
    "windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 1080,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "AppName",
        "width": 1920
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here're few ways to get it in Rust:

**1. Using `std::env`**

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn get_env(name: &str) -> String {
    std::env::var(String::from(name)).unwrap_or(String::from(""))
}
```

Then in typescript:

```js
import { invoke } from "@tauri-apps/api/core";

function get_env(name: string) {
  return await invoke("get_env", { name });
}
```

**2. Using Vite**

Only with `VITE_` prefixes:

```js
import.meta.env.VITE_DEVELOPER_MINDSET
```

**3. Using SvelteKit**

In SSG mode only and only starting with `PUBLIC_` prefixes.

```js
import * as env from "$env/static/public";
console.log(import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DEVELOPER_MINDSET); // works
```

**4. Pure Rust**

Install crate: `cargo add dotenv`

Then in your rust code, load from `.env` using:

```rust
dotenv::dotenv().ok();
```

Or using macro:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate dotenv_codegen;
```

And then in rust you can use `dotenv` macro:

```rust
println!("{}", dotenv!("DEVELOPER_MINDSET"));
```

There are couple more options on how to connect pulling and embedded environment variables inside backend and frontend of the Tauri app in my [tutorial](https://www.developermindset.com/tauri-env/).

Comment: Here's a youtube video about tauri environment variables – https://youtu.be/eFRl38t-D1U